# Flyway apply migrations from an specific JAR dependency

Tags: java, flyway

I have some SQL migrations packed into a JAR (lets call it `com.example:sql-migrations`). Scripts are located in `src/main/resources/db/migration` in that package and are included inside the JAR.

In a separate project, I'm including that JAR as dependency and I'm successfully using Flyway to apply those migrations by using `.locations("classpath:db/migration")` while configuring Flyway.

Up until here everything is working and those are being applied. BUT this is giving me a bit of bad feeling as it seems Flyway is looking for any resource matching that path and applying it no matter from which JAR its being found. This might result in some security problems. Is there any way to restrict that classpath resource to a specific JAR? something like `"classpath:com.example:sql-migrations!db/migration"`? I tried many combinations and non works, also nothing on docs.

PS: This question might look similar to lots of the others related to Flyway, but its actually never asked.

Comment: How that could be a security concern when particular team is responsible for contents of final application? Just do not pack there anything you should not pack.

Comment: so we should avoid the whole Java ecosystem? we have 3rd party libs, open source ones, ... and looking at the amount of supply chain attacks recently, its such a naive stance to ignore it. Flyway shall provide a way to limit the search to specific JARs.

Comment: you are looking for technological solution where the organisational one is required: if you do not trust 3rd-party libraries - do not include them into application (3rd-party library might contain malicious jdbc driver, why do you not concern about that?). BTW, just change flyway namespace from common `db/migration` to something more specific for your application or organisation and get ultimate confidence about "security".